# Looping through all elements in XML VB.NET

Tags: .net, xml

I was wondering if there is any way to loop through all elements in an XML using XmlDocument and storing the elements in a String array. I want to be able to do this with any XML that contains elements. All of the answers I've seen here so far, are made for specific XML files. I would like to do this with any XML in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done by enumerating all `Descendants()` of an `XDocument`:

```
Module Program

    Sub Main()

        Dim xDocument = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                        <root>
                            <node1>
                                <node2></node2>
                            </node1>
                            <node1>
                                <node2></node2>
                            </node1>
                        </root>

        For Each el In xDocument.Descendants()
            Console.WriteLine(el.Name)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

You can create an instance of an `XDocument` from a VB XML literal (as above), from a string (`XDocument.Parse("<root></root>")` or from a file/stream (`XDocument.Load(fileName)`).